# CSS 5-square background pattern

Tags: css, background, background-image

I'm looking for a succinct CSS solution to create a specific pattern for an element's background. The pattern is the tiny one with red dots at the top of this page:

[image: 1.png]

Here is the image above magnified so it is easier to see the pattern:

[image: 2.png]

I care only about the red dot pattern, not borders.

I have tried many variations like the following but can't seem to crack it:

```
div {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(-45deg, red 25%, transparent 25%), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, transparent 25%), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, red 75%), 
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, red 75%);
    background-size: 2px 2px;
    background-position: 40.5% 0, 40.5% 52%, 0 0, 0.05% 52%;
}
```

Comment: you could use a tool like http://www.patternify.com/ to generate a repeating base64 png rather than using a gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @haxxxton went above board with his answer and I commend it, I ultimately figured out how to do this with CSS only.

It matches the sample background pattern exactly and is easy to change the color.

Here is what I came up with:

```
.background {
  background-color: white; 
  background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, red 0%, red 50%),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, white 0%, white 50%),  
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, white 0%, white 50%),  
    repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, red 0%, red 50%); 
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-position: -1px, 2px, 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: If youre happy im happy :) but this doesnt 'exactly' match the pattern in the question :p but is definitely easier to update, and should work more successfully in an html email. Be warned that html email backgrounds have notorious issues across some mailing clients, so dont forget to look up some compatability tables, use browser prefixes, and test in various mail clients.

Comment: @haxxxton The pattern is exactly identical as the sample in Chrome and Opera, but it is somewhat different in Firefox and IE:  https://jsfiddle.net/5z7n4cd1/

Comment: OSX Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit), has solid white lines that appear between the red lines: https://jsfiddle.net/5z7n4cd1/1/ (unlike your sample :) ), regardless, im happy you're happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to emulate the pattern using CSS psuedo elements `:before` and `:after` to "cover" parts of the repeating "checkerboard" red and white background. Unfortunately, this requires you to use a colour other than `transparent` for the "gaps" in the red, so that the later tiles can "cover" the red checkerboard parts.

The following [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1hwht0d/1/) uses `transform:scale(10)` to better show the pattern, Im not sure if you intend to put content inside the element with this background, but I wanted to show that the psuedo elements sit behind any internal content, but the following code just contains the relevant css

```
.background {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%, red),
        linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, white 25%, white 75%, red 75%, red);
    background-size: 2px 2px;
    background-position:0 0, 1px 1px;
}
.background:after,
.background:before{
    content:"";
    /* position the psuedo elements entirely over the background */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    /* create "cover" gradients */
    background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, white 25%, transparent 25%);
    background-size:4px 4px;
    background-position:0 0;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    /* set a negative z-index so content is above it */
    z-index:-1;
}
.background:before{
    background-position:2px 2px;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Taking the base64 png generator code from http://patternify.com/ and hardcoding the design, we end up with JS that will output the image code you'd need to make the html email background image tiles. You just need to change the `color1` and `color2` variables as needed.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yson1hoj/1/)**

**JS**

```
//create a new canvas element to hold the sized down pattern
var output = document.getElementById('base64-code');
var patcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var patcontext = patcanvas.getContext('2d');
var color1 = [255,0,0,1]; // red
var color2 = [255,255,255,1]; // white
var matrix = [
    [color2, color1, color2, color1],
    [color1, color2, color2, color2],
    [color2, color1, color2, color1],
    [color2, color2, color1, color2]
];
/*
        the matrix variable represents the width, then height of the pattern, so we're sort of drawing it on its side and mirrored
        .#.#
        #...
        .#.#
        ..#.

        will result in
        .#..
        #.#.
        ...#
        #.#.
    */

function drawPattern() {
    //set width and height, which also clears the canvas
    patcanvas.width = 4;
    patcanvas.height = 4;

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                tileColor = matrix[i][j];
                patcontext.fillStyle = "rgba(" + tileColor[0] + ", " + tileColor[1] + ", " + tileColor[2] + ", " + tileColor[3] + ")";
                patcontext.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //get the preview canvas and clear it as well
    var pcanvas = document.getElementById("preview-canvas");
    pcanvas.width = pcanvas.width;
    var pcontext = pcanvas.getContext("2d");

    //create a pattern from the pattern canvas and fill the preview canvas with it
    var pattern = pcontext.createPattern(patcanvas, "repeat");
    pcontext.rect(0, 0, pcanvas.width, pcanvas.height);
    pcontext.fillStyle = pattern;
    pcontext.fill();

    //also update the code
    var dataURL = patcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    output.innerHTML = dataURL;
};
drawPattern();
```

Comment: Really nice work. In my situation, I need this for HTML in GMail emails. The only CSS that works is inline and so I believe this takes psudeo elements off the table. I should have specified that in the question and I'm sorry. Can you do this without them?

Comment: if you just want a checkerboard pattern you definitely do it, its the "white plus" shapes that make this hard to do with just gradients. honestly, the inline base64 image solution provided by the patternify.com site is likely to be your best shot if this needs to be emails

Comment: The problem with an image is that the colors used (red and white here) can be anything and need to be set dynamically.  So a gradient or some other CSS mechanism seems like the more doable approach.

Comment: @astudent, what is generating the email html? php? js?

Comment: @astudent, If its js, i have added code that will dynamically generate the base64 png data you'd need. php would be a little trickier as it would require playing with their image and GD library which im unfamiliar with

Comment: Thank you for the extra effort.

Comment: Thanks again. Please see my answer.