# Square pattern as background on a div (with pure CSS)

Tags: css, background

I'm trying to find how to build this pattern, with parallel squares (each square with about 3px) to put as background on a div using css (not using an image background and repeating the X axe). I can only find chess patterns, which is not the case. Could anyone help me with that challenge? thank you really much!

I did search for hours on google how to make this pattern here:

[image]

Comment: ...Why not just use that very image itself as a [**`background-image`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)?

Comment: Because I really want to learn how to do that using pure code, like the gradient technique to do that. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, It would be easier just to use that image as a background image... theres no reason to make this using pure html and css.. it would be a nightmare trying to make it responsive and it would probably slow your website down having to render 1,000,000 tiny squares

Comment: Thank you so much Juvenile for the gentle answer. It will be my choice, creating a simple 4 squares png and put it as a background-image repeated X and Y. You're right, trying to learn this new technique and not even have it working for every browser would be worst. Thank you so much for your opinion :)

Comment: I try to tweak with this one without luck, but this might be a good start point for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478639/css-5-square-background-pattern

Answer (score 52, accepted):

While your specific example is easier to make using a repeating image, [more interesting effects](https://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) can be realized using pure CSS so it's not a useless skill to have. As always when trying to learn something web-related, MDN is a good place to start and has [a pretty good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients) about CSS gradients. Here's the short of it.

CSS gradients are functions which return images. The simplest one is `linear-gradient`. Picture a horizontal line in your head and place a series of points along this line to which you'll assign a color. The function will automatically make the color transition smoothly between these points.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 50%, green 75%, yellow 100%);
}
```

As you can see, the gradient is pure black from the left until we get to the middle (50%) then it starts to fade to green and finally to yellow. This modern and verbose syntax is very intuitive. We can actually remove some of that to get the same effect.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, green 75%, yellow);
}
```

This time, we got rid of the `black 0%` stop. If we don't have a stop at 0%, the color of the first stop is simply used to fill the empty space. We also didn't specify the position of the last stop (yellow), so it was automatically placed at 100%.

When we set two consecutive color stops at the same point, we get interesting results:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    black, black 50%,
    green 50%, green 75%,
    yellow 75%, yellow
  );
}
```

Here we told the gradient function to be black from the start to 50%, then to be green from 50% to 75%, then to be yellow from 75% to the end. By leaving no room between color stops, we abuse gradients to produce solid colors. Of course we didn't need the first black and the last yellow.

Something I haven't mentioned yet is that the generated gradient isn't actually the size of the full element, and it is actually tiled across it like any background-image. If we change the angle of the gradient, it becomes quite apparent.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg, black 50%, green 50%, green 75%, yellow 75%
  );
  background-size: 100% 40px;
}
```

As you can see, the gradient is now at a 45degree angle so it makes a triangular shape, but it is only 40px tall and tiled, which creates an interesting zig-zag.

Since the gradient function generates an image, we can actually tile said image to create a repeating pattern. I prefer using percentages when making gradients and then specifying the total size of the gradient using background-size, like this:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #617ca2 50%, #28487d 50%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

This creates a gradient that is #617ca2 from 0 to 50% and then #28487d from 50 to 100%, and considering 100% as 10px.

The final trick is that we can have multiple layers of background and use transparent colors in our gradients.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, #28487d 50%),
                    linear-gradient(to right, #617ca2 50%, #28487d 50%);
  background-size: 10px 10px, 10px 10px;
}
```

You can also use repeating-linear-gradient directly instead, but you'll have to set the gradient in pixels and be a little more explicit when it comes to the first and last color stops. I'm less familiar with this method, and the result might be slightly different.

```css
body {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 5px, #28487d 5px, #28487d 10px),
                    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #617ca2, #617ca2 5px, #28487d 5px, #28487d 10px);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. Thank you so much Jacque! I will analyse all your answer and practice here. I am going also to check about the good practice of using it or just using the background-image repeated to check which option is better in terms of performance. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

With the [support for conic-gradient](https://caniuse.com/css-conic-gradients) now being pretty good you can achieve square patterns like these quite easily.

```css
body {
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(
    #28487d 90deg,
    #28487d 90deg 180deg,
    #617ca2 180deg 270deg,
    #28487d 270deg
  );
}
```

The `background-size` constrains it to a square, and the `conic-gradient` divides that square up into four parts at right angles to be colored however you like.

Comment: Oh, that's a clever use of conic-gradient indeed. Though you do not need four color stops: `conic-gradient(#28487d 75%, #617ca2 75%)` is enough :)

Answer (score -5):

This can be achieved using css grid. Here's the code snippet for it:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container{
                top:5%;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(10px,1fr));
                grid-gap:3px;
                grid-template-rows: repeat(100,10px);
            }
            .container div{
                background-color:aqua;
            }
        </style>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"></div>
        <script>
                for(let i=0; i<1000; i++){
                    $('.container').prepend($('<div></div>'));
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is overkill. It can be made using only CSS, no HTML and certainly no JS.

Comment: With such coding..it wont be able to used as a background but as a main content...try showing some text over this you will get your answer...but still a nyc try :)